# Make sure iframe is selected right away

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This is possibly a stupid question, but when I'm using an iframe, particular aspects (controlled by event listeners in the html file that is used by the iframe) are available if you click on the frame. If you click outside of the iframe it looses access to those controls and event listeners. Is there a way to make an **iframe be already clicked?**. Sorry about the bad wording, but I haven't found a single way to do this, any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried the `focus()` function?

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: If that works, you should make it an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wasn't sure if he tried it, and I wasn't sure if it would work.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney Yeah, I agree, can you make your answer a question so I can give you credit? It worked perfectly, sorry ijse, yours didn't really work, maybe I have an old version of my browsers :P

Comment: @FengHuo: No, it's that in ijse's code, the `focus` wasn't being called until/unless the frame already had focus and the focus was moving away from it. Hopefully Jeffrey will come back and post an answer you can accept. If he doesn't, it's perfectly acceptable to post an answer yourself and accept that (once the site allows you to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
iframe.onblur = function() {
  iframe.focus();
}
```

Comment: That will (try to) focus the frame if someone tries to take focus away from it, rather than focussing the frame on page load.

Comment: I don't think you would want to do this. It would forcefully focus the iframe even if the user unfocuses it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<iframe id="iframe" autofocus="true" src="page.html"></iframe>

<script>
    document.getElementById('iframe').focus();
</script>
```

The autofocus attribute in HTML5 can also force an element's focus. In this example, it's redundant.

Comment: There's no such thing as `autofocus` in the `<iframe>` tag in HTML itself.