# Iframe detect keys, without click

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, and to take up less space on the users computer, I am putting certain features on the cloud (via github)

The Issue is that for the Iframe to detect the arrow keys, you have to click on it first (focus), and that is annoying for some of the test users.

Does anyone know how to make the Iframe automatically focus without being click on?

**Update:**

I found the post: [Make sure iframe is selected right away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751734/make-sure-iframe-is-selected-right-away), but It doesn't seem to work. my code is as follows:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById(iframe);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
iframe.focus()
})
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://2048cupcake.github.io/16384/index.html" height="475" width="350" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script src="iframe.js"></script>
```

Comment: Events only register in an iframe if it is focused.

Comment: is it possible to auto-focus?

Comment: Probably is... have never tried it or looked into it. Should be an easy search

Comment: I updated my post @charlietfl doesn't seem to work

Comment: Move first line inside the DOMContentLoaded handler to be safe. Also try in several browsers

Comment: Didn't do anything :(, and this is a chrome extension, so it doesn't matter if it works elsewear

Comment: Quite possible it is a newer security restriction since iframes can be used for malicious activity. Some things you used to be able to do programtically now can only be done in user triggered events

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Note also should put the DOMContentLoaded eventListener on `window`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: @charlietfl still doesn't work